# How to return a boolean on whether a list is at a certain size?

Tags: python-3.x, list, boolean

I'm doing a leetcode problem where i need to design a Circular Deque sructure. One of the function is to check if the current container(i'm using a list) is empty and return a boolean value.
The first way i thought about was:
`return cur_list is None`
but it sometimes gives a wrong answer compared to the given answer.
then i turned to use:
`return len(cur_list)==0`
and this works fine.
How is this happening? Are they not the same?

Comment: I'm sorry. The title of this question should be ' how to return a boolean on whether a list is empty',I made a mistake and do not know how to edit it after posted.

Comment: No, that is **absolutely** not the same thing. `cur_list is None` is checking if `cur_list` is the *same exact object* as `None`.  `len(cur_list)==0` checks if the list has a length of exactly 0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are definitely not the same. In Python the lines,

```
foo is bar
id(foo) == id(bar)
```

are equivalent.

If you read the docs for `id` https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id, you will see that using the `is` keyword is literally checking if the two objects are the same.

You should only use the `is` keyword for checking if an object is `None`. This is because for performance, Python creates one `None` object at startup which is then used whenever a variable is made `None`. So if two variables are `None`, then they will literally be the same object, and `foo is bar` will be `True`.

Since an empty list `[]`, is definitely a different object than `None`, for checking if a list is empty you should definitely do `len(cur_list)==0`

Comment: Now i got it, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same.

A list is a Python Object that may be empty. For example, a list with a non-zero number of elements would be something like

```
my_list = [1, 2, 3]
```

However, a list with no elements (which is in fact still a List Object) would look like

```
my_empty_list = []
```

Which is different from the NoneType Object in Python:

```
my_none_obj = None
```

Namely, notice that `[] != None`. One way to think about this is that `None` is in some sense telling you that your variable is not pointing to a list at all.`None` is identifiable yet different than an empty data structure.

Comment: "is essentially a null-pointer" really not a great way of thinking about it unless you come from C. Even then, not a great analogy.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation, i now got it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Completely agree - this is why I said it was not completely precise and made the reservation that I made this comparison because None may be used when have a variable that we think is a list but is actually pointing to a None Object rather than an empty list. Regardless, I agree it is a bad analogy and I edited my answer appropriately.